# Is this the proper use of U-Substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I am part of an R&D role at my job, and I have been given the task to model the magnetic field of a bowl shaped permanent magnet. So this isn't part of a textbook and I have no idea if the answer I am getting is actually correct for now, therefore I am more interested to make sure my procedure is correct of using the U-Substitution. I am essentially trying to find the total sum of the the distances of the surface of a bowl to a point "P" somewhere on the +y axis.

This is my integral:

$$
r = \int_0^H \sqrt{a^2+ (x+h)^2} \space\space dh
$$

These are my steps:

let $u =x +h$ ;$\frac{du}{dh}=1$

$$
r =\int_0^H \sqrt{a^2+ u^2} \space \space du
$$

let $t = a^2+u^2 $ ; $\frac{dt}{du}=2u$

$$
r =\frac{1}{2u} \int_0^H \sqrt{t} \space \space dt
$$

Solving and plugging back in:

$$
r =\frac{1}{2u} \left(\frac{2}{3} t ^ {\frac{3}{2}}\right)
$$

Plugging all back in:

$$
\frac{1}{2(x+h)} \left(\frac{2}{3}[a^2+(x+h)^2]^\frac{3}{2} \right)
$$

Simplifying...

$$
r = \frac{(a^2 + [x+h]^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{2(x+h)}
$$

There you have it? Are these steps correct?

Thank you very much for helping out.

Comment: Watch your integration borders. I haven't checked, wheter this is unimportant by chance and symmetry in your example, but genereally, the integration borders change when substituting (phi or its inverse is applied to them, depending on your direction)

Comment: I'll look into that as well, thank you.

Comment: @macas I think your answer is correct because you substituted for t and then for u, so not updating the limits won't matter much.

Comment: no - the integration is incorrect: one can't take the $1/2u$ out of the integral, since $u$  is a function. A popular substitution is $u = a \tan \theta$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question has been resolved but here's another way using integration by parts and an integration formula which, in my experience, has been pretty useful to know.  I'm posting this because even though it's a "longer" route, I do think it's good to see alternative approaches.  And to me it feels more straightforward or natural, especially since I have no experience using hyperbolic trig substitutions.

$$
r = \int_0^H \sqrt{a^2+ (x+h)^2} \, dh
$$
First substitute $t = x+h$, so then $dt = dh$ and the new limits of integration are $x$ and $x+H$.
$$
r = \int_x^{x+H} \sqrt{a^2+ t^2} \, dt
$$
Now integrate by parts.  Let $u = \sqrt{a^2+t^2}$, so then $dv = dt$, $v = t$, and $du = \dfrac t{\sqrt{a^2+t^2}} \, dt$ and we have
\begin{align*}
  r &= \int_x^{x+H} \sqrt{a^2+ t^2} \, dt\\[0.3cm]
    &= t\sqrt{a^2+t^2}\bigg|_{t=x}^{t=x+H} - \int_x^{x+H} \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a^2+t^2}} \, dt\\[0.3cm]
    &= (x+H)\sqrt{a^2+(x+H)^2} - x\sqrt{a^2+x^2} - \int_x^{x+H} \frac{\color{red}{a^2} +t^2\color{red}{-a^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+t^2}} \, dt\\[0.3cm]
    &= (x+H)\sqrt{a^2+(x+H)^2} - x\sqrt{a^2+x^2} - \int_x^{x+H} \frac{a^2 +t^2}{\sqrt{a^2+t^2}} \, dt + \int_x^{x+H} \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+t^2}} \, dt\\[0.3cm]
    &= (x+H)\sqrt{a^2+(x+H)^2} - x\sqrt{a^2+x^2} - \underbrace{\int_x^{x+H} \sqrt{a^2+t^2} \, dt}_{\text{This is $r$}} + a^2 \ln(\sqrt{a^2+t^2}+t)\bigg|_{t=x}^{t=x+H}\\[0.3cm]
   r &= (x+H)\sqrt{a^2+(x+H)^2} - x\sqrt{a^2+x^2} - r + a^2 \ln(\sqrt{a^2+(x+H)^2}+x+H) - a^2\ln(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+x)
\end{align*}

Now add $r$ to both sides and divide by 2.

Comment: I know this is the longer way to it, but much more easier to read and more natural than hyperbolic functions. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 4):

1. When you substitute, you have to change the limits as well: $x$ varies between $0$ and $H$, so $u=x+h$ varies between $H$ and $x+H$.
2. This is in some sense a more serious problem, and it changes the nature of the computation a lot: $u$ depends on $t$, so you can't take it out of the integral after you substitute $t=a^2+u^2$. In fact, I'm fairly sure you won't get very far with this substitution if you tried to carry on, because the expressions won't get simpler.

---

Here is how I would do it. Let $x+h=a\sinh{u}$. Then $dh = a\cosh{u}\, du$, and $\sqrt{a^2+(x+h)^2} = \sqrt{a^2+a^2\sinh^2{u}} = a\cosh{u}$, so we need to compute
$$ a^2 \int \cosh^2{u} \, du. $$
$\cosh^2{u} = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cosh{2u})$, which has antiderivative
$$ \frac{u}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\sinh{2u} = \frac{u}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sinh{u}\cosh{u}. $$
Undoing the substitution then gives
$$ \int \sqrt{a^2+(x+h)^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \left( a^2\arg\sinh{\left(\frac{x+h}{a}\right)} + (x+h)\sqrt{a^2+(x+h)^2} \right). $$
The first term is reexpressible using $ \arg\sinh{z}=\log{(z+\sqrt{1+z^2})}$, so
$$ \int \sqrt{a^2+(x+h)^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \left( a^2\log{\left(\frac{x+h+\sqrt{a^2+(x+h)^2}}{a}\right)} + (x+h)\sqrt{a^2+(x+h)^2} \right), $$
and then you can put whatever limits in that you want.

Comment: Thank you! It has been a while since I have done any U-substitution on this kind of scale.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is a much easier integration than using $x+h=a\tan{\theta}$, because integrating $\sec^3$ is a pain.

Comment: @Chappers - being the one who suggested $\tan \theta $ above, I absolutely agree. But in my distant childhood, hyperbolic functions weren't 'in'; I later taught cal in a number of places, but that was more than 15 years ago. Still, I don't recall hyp. f'ns  appearing in the std curriculum then either  - do they now?

Comment: @peterag, I think it's a regional thing.  They don't seem to be as "popular" here in the US but many international students I've known have studied them to the point of using them in substitutions like this.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that the $\log$ is really $\ln$ in case @macas doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you make a $u$-substitution, you must change the bounds of the integral. For instance, you initially have the integral (with respect to $h$) going from $h=0$ to $h=H$. Then you make the substitution $u=x+h$. Then $u$ varies from $u=x+0=x$ to $u=x+H$. So your new integral with respect to $u$ should have lower bound $x$ and upper bound $x+H$. Similarly with the next substitution.

Comment: $H$ is the upper limit and $h$ is the variable.

Comment: @A---B I just changed the original post to have the upper limit to H to make more sense.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not see the change.

Comment: @A---B No problem!

Comment: Fixed my answer.